# Compatibility of JQuery Mobile 1.3 and JQuery UI 1.10

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I tried to to use JQ Mobile as main UI, and JQ UI solely for implementing a drag and drop function. When including JQM library first and then followed by JQ UI, some widgets and JQM functionalities will not behave as expected; when including UI first, the draggable and droppable functions seem to be undefined, as indicated by Firebug. Is there any workaround? Thanks.

```
<!-- include JQuery UI before JQ Mobile -->
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.3/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>  
<link href="jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Firstly you're better off declaring CSS _before_ JavaScript - and also to show some Console Log Errors.

Comment: On what devices are you testing this? Draggable and Droppable work just fine in desktop browsers, but ONLY when jQuery Mobile js is initialized last.

Comment: I am using WorkLight to develop an application on mobile devices. Currently I am using browser simulator to test it.